# selecting 5 doughnuts counting problem

Tags: combinatorics

(a) For breakfast, you have a choice of 4 kinds of doughnuts: glazed,
chocolate, sugar and plain. In how many different ways can you choose 5 of
these doughnuts?

(b) What is the answer in the general case that there are k kinds of dough-
nuts and you want to select n doughnuts?

i think you have to use the Convolution Rule for this problem, but not really sure how to apply it

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3$, and $x_4$ be the numbers glazed, chocolate, sugar, and plain doughnuts that you choose. Then each of these numbers must be a non-negative integer, and

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=5\;.\tag{1}$$

Each solution of $(1)$ in non-negative integers gives you a possible choice of doughnuts, and each possible choice of doughnuts gives you a solution to $(1)$ in non-negative integers. Thus, your problem reduces to counting the solutions to $(1)$ in non-negative integers. This kind of problem is often called a [stars-and-bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29) problem; the linked article gives you the answer,

$$\binom{5+4-1}{4-1}=\binom83\;,$$

and a pretty decent explanation of the reasoning behind it. Between what I’ve done here with (a) and what you find in the article, you should be able to make a good stab at (b), but feel free to ping me if you get stuck.

Comment: what do you mean by "(1) in non-negative integers"?

Comment: @dotdotdot: $(1)$ is a reference to equation $(1)$, the first displayed equation: you’ll find its label, $(1)$, at the far righthand side. The phrase *in non-negative integers* modifies *solutions*: you’re looking for solutions in non-negative integers to the equation labelled $(1)$.

Comment: right... didn't see the (1)

Comment: quick question... when do you know its appropriate to use the stars and bars method... is there a clue i need to look for in a problem to determine if the stars and bars method applies?

Comment: @dotdotdot: Whenever you can recast it as a problem involving solving an equation of the form $x_1+\ldots+x_m=n$, the stars-and-bars idea is likely to be at least part of the solution. Alternatively, if you can think of it as counting the number of ways of distributing $n$ identical objects amongst $m$ distinct containers (so that $x_k$ is the number in container $k$), it’s a stars-and-bars problem. But I won’t conceal from you that sometimes it’s not obvious that a problem can be thought of in this way. [This problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/289734/12042) is perhaps an example.