# Number of integer solutions to $|x_1|+|x_2|+...+|x_n| \le m$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

Show that the following two inequalities have the same number of integer solutions.

(A) $|x_1|+|x_2|+...+|x_n| \le m$

(B) $|y_1|+|y_2|+...+|y_m| \le n$, where m and n are two positive integers.

Well, I tried to solve this by using lattice paths argument which is effective to show that A and B have the same number of non-negative solutions but failed. I want to know bijective proofs and also closed form of the number of solutions if it exists.

Comment: Have you tried proof by the method of *double counting*? See 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the inequality $$x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n \le m,$$

where $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are integer variables. We know that the numbers of *positive* and *non-negative* solution vectors $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ satisfying this inequality are $\binom{m}{n}$ and $\binom{m+n}{n}$, respectively (see e.g., [LINK-1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382935/combinatorics-distribution-number-of-integer-solutions-concept-explanation) and [LINK-2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293353/integer-solutions)).

The number of *non-negative* integer solutions to $$|x_1|+|x_2|+\dots+|x_n| \le m,$$ is the same as the number of *non-negative* integer solutions to $$x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n \le m,$$

which is equal to $\binom{m+n}{n}$. For the same reason, the number of *non-negative* integer solutions to $$|x_1|+|x_2|+\dots+|x_m| \le n,$$ is equal to $\binom{m+n}{m}$. Since we have

$$\binom{m+n}{m} = \binom{m+n}{n},$$

we can conclude that the numbers of non-negative solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_i| \le m$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{m} |x_i| \le n$ are the same.

**The general case:**

Consider a non-negative solution of $\sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_i| \le m$ in which $1 \le k \le \min(m,n)$ variables are positive ($k>m$ is impossible). The number of such solutions is equal to the number of ways we can select $k$ variables from $n$ variables times the number of *positive* solutions to

$$x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k \le m.$$

Since there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to select $k$ variables from $n$ variables and there are $\binom{m}{k}$ positive solutions to the last inequality, there are $\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{k}$ non-negative solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_i| \le m$ with $k$ positive variables. On the other hand, there are $2^k$ number of solutions corresponding to each of these solutions that can be achieved by changing sign of the variables. So the total number of integer solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_i| \le m$ would be

$$N_1 = 1+\sum_{k=1}^{\min(m,n)} 2^k \binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{k}.$$

Note that we added $1$ as we also need to consider the solution vector $(x_1,\dots,x_n) = (0,\dots,0)$. For the same reason, the number of solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^{m} |x_i| \le n$ is equal to

$$N_2 = 1+\sum_{k=1}^{\min(m,n)} 2^k \binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{k}.$$ It is clear that $N_1 = N_2$.

Comment: Check your general case.  Did you mean to write the number of positive solutions to $$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_{\color{red}{n}} \leq m$$ is equal to $\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{k}$?

Comment: No, the number of positive solutions to $$x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k \le m,$$ is equal to $ \binom{m}{k}$. Because there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to select $k$ variables from $n$ variables the total number of non-negative solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| \le m$ with $k$ positive variables is equal to $\binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{k}$.

Comment: I see.  You have already selected $k$ of the $n$ variables, which is why you were focusing on the inequality $$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k \leq m$$

Comment: Thanks, I modified the question to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The following generating function approach  proves the symmetry, but does not give a final formula as simple as Opt's answer.

We begin with $$x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n\leq m\ .\tag{1}$$ Consider the set of all functions $$f:\quad [n]\to{\mathbb Z}, \qquad k\mapsto x_k\ .\tag{2}$$
The *value* $v(f)$ of such a function is defined to be $$v(f):=z^{|x_1|+\ldots+|x_n|}\ ,$$ where $z$ is an indeterminate. If $n=1$ the total value of all $f:\>[1]\to{\mathbb Z}$  is given by the formal power series $$1+2z+2z^2+2z^3+\ldots={1+z\over1-z}\ .$$
The distributive law then implies that for arbitrary $n\geq1$ the total value of all $f$ in $(2)$ is given by
$$S:=\left({1+z\over1-z}\right)^n\ .$$
Each $f$ with $\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|=m$ contributes $z^m$ to $S$, hence the number of these $f$s is the coefficient of $z^m$ in $S$. Since we want the number of solutions of the *inequality* $(1)$ we multiply $S$ by $1+z+z^2+\ldots={1\over1-z}$ and now determine the coefficient of $z^m$ in
$$S':={(1+z)^n\over(1-z)^{n+1}}=\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}z^j\cdot\sum_{k=0}^\infty{n+k\choose k} z^k\ .$$
This coefficient comes to
$$\sum_{j+k=m}{n\choose j}{n+k\choose k}=\sum_{j=0}^{\min\{m,n\}}{n\choose j}{n+m-j\choose m-j}\ .$$
Chasing factorials allows to rewrite the last sum as
$${m+n\choose m}\sum_{j=0}^{\min\{m,n\}}{{m\choose j}{n\choose j}\over{m+n\choose j}}\ ,$$
which is obviously symmetric in $m$ and $n$.